# No results with DISTINCT - Multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I am trying to run the following query which gets data from two tables but I get no results:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT([dbo].[SF].Assignment), [X].Code 
 FROM [dbo].[SF], [dbo].[X]
 WHERE (CHARINDEX([X].Code, [dbo].[SF].Assignment COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) > 0)

    AND [dbo].[SF].Code = 'NULL'
```

When I remove the DISTINCT, I get way too many results because of my big data set that causes an out of memory exception.

Comment: Input/ output desired

Comment: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-distinct/    Do not use parenthesis with DISTINCT

Comment: Do you really have the string literal 'NULL" in your columns? The reason this isn't returning anything is either both tables are empty or far more likely is that your where predicates have filtered out any results.

Comment: `DISTINCT` won't reduce a resultset from some rows to zero rows. You must have changed something else apart from adding that

Comment: On a side note, you should discontinue the use of implicit JOINs.  That is, don't use `FROM [dbo].[SF], [dbo].[X]` but rather `FROM [dbo].[SF] INNER JOIN [dbo].[X] ON ...`  Implicit joins are deprecated and will be removed from SQL Server.

Comment: @squillman while I totally agree that everybody should use ANSI-92 style joins I don't remember ever seeing that the older ANSI-89 style implicit joins have been deprecated.

Comment: @SeanLange Ooh, I thought I had.  I will try to find that!  Maybe I just need more coffee today...  I'll let you know if I do find it.

Comment: @squillman aside from me being forced to change a few things here and there (tally tables) I think it would be great if that "feature" went away.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Didn't realize I was doing so much wrong!!

Comment: @Tab Alleman I removed the parenthesis with the DISTINCT which was a good start.

Comment: @squillman I also changed the join to an inner join and specified the field which joins the two. I noticed that was missing from the "implicit join" that I wrote. I get results now! Also didn't know it would be deprecated.

Comment: @Martin Smith I guess removing the parenthesis with the DISTINCT helped too.

Comment: @SeanLange Hmm.  Boatloads of comments out there saying it is (even from Adam Mechanic) but I can't find official MS mention of it.  Just the old `*=` / `=* `OUTER JOIN syntax.

Comment: @squillman yeah I knew the *= syntax was dead but I have not seen anything saying the ANSI-89 style is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Removing parentheses with the DISTINCT as well as changing to an INNER JOIN fixed my issues. @Tab Alleman and @squillman can add answer here so I could mark them as correct.